# get div value from inside another div?

Tags: javascript, html

so I have a draggable HTML div element:

```
<div id="server" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)">Server</div>
```

and a target div:

```
<div id="target1" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondrop="return dragDrop(event)" ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
```

if I drag the draggable into the target, then how do I get the value inside of the draggable if I only have the reference to the target that the draggable is in?

Comment: I am a little unclear what you are asking. Couldnt you get the value of what you need any time by referrencing an elements `id`?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking to use the `dataTransfer.setData` method on the drag event and the `datatransfer.getData` method on the drop event. These methods will allow you to pass data between your elements.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  var newText = ev.target.innerText;
  newText = "I've been dropped!";
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("divData", newText);
  console.log(ev.target); //available data
}

function drop(ev) {
  var dragElemID = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var dragElemData = ev.dataTransfer.getData("divData");
  var draggedElem = document.getElementById(dragElemID)
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.target.appendChild(draggedElem);
  ev.target.children[0].innerText = dragElemData;
}
```

```css
#div1{
  border:1px solid;
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
}

#drag1{
  background-color:lightblue;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Target Div</div>

<div id="drag1"draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Drop Div</div>
```

Comment: I was asking if it was poosible to access the dropped div value without ut begin in a drop function and already in the target and only having a reference to the target